# How to edit Model property as HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I created module for orchard.
I have the following Model:

```
public class SliderPart : ContentPart<SliderPartRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public string Slide1
    {
        get { return Record.Slide1; }
        set { Record.Slide1 = value; }
    }
    [Required]
    public string Slide3
    {
        get { return Record.Slide3; }
        set { Record.Slide3 = value; }
    }
    [Required]
    public string Slide2
    {
        get { return Record.Slide2; }
        set { Record.Slide2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Let say I also have editor template for it:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Slide1, new { @class = "text" })

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Slide2, new { @class = "text" })

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Slide3, new { @class = "text" })
```

How to make my fields editable as HTML, like body on Pages module does?

Any idea?
Maybe some attribute to set at Model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     @{ 
    Script.Require("OrchardTinyMce");
     }

    @Html.TextArea("Slide1", Model.Slide1, 25, 80,
     new Dictionary {
        {"class", "html tinymce"},
        {"data-mediapicker-uploadpath",""},
        {"data-mediapicker-title",T("Insert/Update Media")
        }
     })


and etc for 2nd and 3rd
```